# golang: nested struct to nested json or json

Tags: go

I am trying to apply the ddd concepts to my go project

and then I have an entity with a nested struct like this:

```
type Person struct {
    Id       string
    Name     valueObject.Name
    Email    valueObject.Email
    Password valueObject.Password
    Created  time.Time
    Updated  time.Time
}

    func NewPerson(name valueObject.Name, email valueObject.Email, password valueObject.Password) *Person {
        return &Person{
            Id:       "a",
            Name:     name,
            Email:    email,
            Password: password,
            Created:  time.Now(),
            Updated:  time.Now(),
        }
    }
```

all my object values has a structure similar to this:

```
type Email struct {
    address string
}

func NewEmail(address string) (Email, error) {
    isValid := valid(address)
    if !isValid {
        return Email{}, ErrEmail
    }
    return Email{address}, nil
}

func (e Email) Value() string {
    return e.address
}

func (e Email) Format() string {
    return strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(e.Value()))
}

func (e Email) Equals(e2 Email) bool {
    return e.Value() == e2.Value()
}
```

and then as I have a struct that is nested I thought of creating a ToJSON function, to return my data, and I also need to exclude some of the return as a password:

```
type personJson struct {
    id        string
    name      string
    email     string
    createdAt time.Time
    updatedAt time.Time
}
func (p *Person) ToJSON() personJson {
    email := p.Email.Value()
    name := p.Name.FullName()
    person := personJson{id: "dasdas", email: email, name: name, createdAt: p.Created, updatedAt: p.Updated}
    return person
}
```

but then in my controller I try to access it, or when I return this ToJSON always comes as {}:

```
type createPersonDTO struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName"`
    Password  string `json:"password"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
}

func (*PersonController) CreateNewPerson(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var dto createPersonDTO
    if err := ctx.BodyParser(&dto); err != nil {
        return utils.CtxError(ctx, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, err)
    }
    email, err := valueObjects.NewEmail(dto.Email)
    if err != nil {
        return utils.CtxError(ctx, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, err)
    }
    name, err := valueObjects.NewName(dto.FirstName, dto.LastName)
    if err != nil {
        return utils.CtxError(ctx, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, err)
    }
    password, err := valueObjects.NewPassword(dto.Password)
    if err != nil {
        return utils.CtxError(ctx, http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, err)
    }
    person := entities.NewPerson(name, email, password)
    return ctx.Status(http.StatusOK).JSON(person.ToJSON())
}
```

my res.body is always an empty json

Comment: The json marshaller will only export public fields. Uppercase your struct fields' first letter to make them public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uppercase the first letter of each field of the struct you want to be exportable to `json.Marshal`:

```
type personJson struct {
    ID        string
    Name      string
    Email     string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```